# How to escape a doublequote-sign inside a (tau) prolog string?

Tags: tau-prolog

I guess there must be an easy answer to this, but I just haven't been able to find it -
I want to include double-quote signs inside tau-prolog strings.. how to do it?

When I try entering it into the Tau-Prolog sandbox (http://tau-prolog.org/sandbox/) I get the following interaction:

```
A = "hello there, \"world\"".

error parsing query: error(syntax_error(unknown_escape_sequence),[line(1),column(4),found('"hello there, \\"')])
```

Any ideas?
Where did I (stupidly) misunderstand things? :)

PS - it's not only a problem in the sandbox - if try to run a Tau-Prolog program (in the browser), and use a double-quote character anywhere inside a string I get the same parsing-problem.

Comment: This is clearly a bug. But reduplicating the `"` does work. Thus `A = "hello there, ""world""".`

Comment: Ok, surprising, but thanks! :) - I can live with that workaround for now

Comment: https://github.com/tau-prolog/tau-prolog/issues/334